# I can install and build rosjava but can't run tutorials

Tags: ros, rosjava, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone post step by step instructions to get the rosjava pub_sub tutorial working. Working on Ubuntu, and I need it to work with Groovy.

So is there anyone who can give a tutorial with step by step instructions s.t. one can get code running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92431/i-can-install-and-build-rosjava-but-can%27t-run-tutorials/) by [larry](https://answers.ros.org/users/7911/larry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems rosjava is changing a lot, you can probably use the code from
https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_extras to get going, until tutorials are updated.

Also look at my updated tutorial code:

https://github.com/tkruse/rosjava_wiki_tutorials

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [larry](https://answers.ros.org/users/7911/larry/) on 2013-10-19**:
Thanks. But it's still not working (the tutorial code doesn't work either).

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-20**:
Both links I gave should now give you projects that compile and run. If they don't for you, post the error you get. Consider asking at rosjava SIG: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-java I started an issue for the tutorials: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/178

**Comment by [larry](https://answers.ros.org/users/7911/larry/) on 2013-10-20**:
Failure Could not determine which tasks to execute. Task installApp not found in root project rosjava.

There are the error messages.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-20**:
Can you open a github issue on that, and paste the log, it will be easier to resolve than here.

**Comment by [larry](https://answers.ros.org/users/7911/larry/) on 2013-10-20**:
I do have a question: why are you not using gradlew?

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-21**:
gradlew is also okay to use, and easy to add. I did not think it was important, but could add it. "gradle installApp" would be run in the tutorials project, not in any other gradle/rosjava project. run "gradle tasks" to see what tasks are configured. (Or gradlew tasks).